# How to show form validation error in react

Tags: reactjs

I do all thing my validation message can print on console but not on page i want my validation error can also shown on form

***this is my App.js i use react 18.2.0 version on my machine***

***I use this as shown error on page <p style={{color: "Red"}}>{errors ?  errors.Name : '' }***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App(){

  const[Name,setName]= useState('');
  const[Email,setEmail]=useState('');
  const[Password,setPassword]=useState('');
  const errors={};


  const handleChange = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setName(e.target.value);

  }
  const handleEmailChange =(e)=>{
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  }
  const handlePasswordChange =(e)=>{
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Name:  ${Name}  \n
            email: ${Email} \n
            Password: ${Password} \n `);
  //console.log(typeof(Name))
            if(!Name || !Email || !Password) {
              console.log('here');
             
                errors.Name="All Fields Are Required!";
            console.log(errors)
                 // return errors;

            }
  };
return(
    <div>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
        <label>Enter Your Name: </label>
        <input type="text" value={Name} onChange={handleChange}></input>
        </div>
        <p style={{color: "Red"}}>{errors ?  errors.Name : '' }</p>
        <div>
        <label>Enter your Email:  </label>
        <input type="email"  value={Email} onChange={handleEmailChange}></input>
        </div>
        {/* <p style={{color: "Red"}}>{FormErrors.Email}</p> */}
        <div>
        <label>Enter your Password:  </label>
        <input type="password"  value={Password} onChange={handlePasswordChange}></input>
        </div>
        {/* <p style={{color: "Red"}}>{FormErrors.Password}</p> */}
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

### Like This

i want if all field is required they give error on all column like name is required email is required password is required i use this else if but it show error one by one like if i empty all field it will only show error on Name field not Password or email field

```
 if (!Name) {
      setErrors({Name: "Name is Required!" });
       console.log(errors.Name);
            }
            else if(!Email){
              setErrors({Email: "Email is Required!"});
            }
            else if(!Password){
              setErrors({Password:"password is Required!"});
            }        
  };
```

Comment: Please try maintaining a state for your error field. Looks like you are using a normal const which may not render your respective ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react is not able to re-render your component instead use `useState` to setErrors

try this

```
 const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

 
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Name:  ${Name}  \n
            email: ${Email} \n
            Password: ${Password} \n `);
    //console.log(typeof(Name))
       if (!Name) {
      setErrors((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          Name: "Name is Required!",
        };
      });
    } else {
      setErrors((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          Name: "",
        };
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: if i use `if (!Name || !Email || !Password)` this  to this `if(!Name) elseif(!Email) elseif(!password)` how i print that

Comment: @gouravkumar can you please elaborate that ?

Comment: @gouravkumar remove else if condtion just put `if`

Comment: yes i also use `if` but  when i use they only give password error not other

Answer (score 1):

**There is a mistake in your code.**

*No Rerender for Error*
You could make an Error state for that like this

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

    if (!Name || !Email || !Password) {
    setErrors("All Fields Are Required!");
}
```

};

**In JSX , Add this at top of Form**

```
 <p style={{color: "Red"}}>{errors ?  errors: '' }</p>
```